# Maps - difference between satellite and hybrid modes

Tags: android

I can see the difference on Google Maps, but on an Android MapActivity
I'm struggling to find the difference.

For 'map' I call: mapView.setSatellite(false);

For 'satellite' I call: mapView.setSatellite(true);

But for hybrid view... I tried playing with
mapView.setStreetView(true); but this doesn't seem to affect anything
either way.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've got the same problem, have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only viewing the streetView, make the following call:

```
mapView.setSatellite(true);
```

That solved it for me. Good luck